# Add menu items to context menu

Tags: javascript, right-click, tidesdk

I am starting to make one of my first apps in Tidesdk and I want to add stuff to the right mouse button menu. (It is usually named the alt menu or context menu.)

How do you do this? It only seems to have the default one, `'Show Inspector'`.

So, how can I alter the default 'context menu' to add and remove my own items and remove the default item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, since no ones answering it, i found it by a bit of off the subject googling, as Tidesdk is pretty much Titanium appcelerator. So this is what I got

```
    var menu = Ti.UI.createMenu();

        menu.addItem('Cut', function() {
            alert('cut');
        });
        menu.addItem('Copy', function() {
            alert('copy');
        });
        menu.addItem('Paste', function() {
            alert('paste');
        });

Ti.UI.getMainWindow().setContextMenu(menu);
```